# Showing Page Loading Message in single application in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to show loading message ...... I am working on single page application in phonegag using jquery mobile.

```
$(document).delegate("#cartaxvalidityPage", "pageinit", function () {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    createCarTaxValidPage();
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});

function createCarTaxValidPage() {
    var buyerList = carHaatDatabaseParsed.BuyerList;
    $("#buyer-listview").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < buyerList.length; i++) {
        var listItem = $('<li> </li>');
        var listAnc = $('<a>  </a>');

        var carImag = "<img " + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64," + buyerList[i].BuyerPhoto + "'/>";

        var listHeader = $('<h3> ' + "Buyer Name: " + buyerList[i].BuyerName + ' </h3>');
        var listParagraph = $('<p> Buyer Id: ' + buyerList[i].BuyerTaxId + ' </p>');
        var listParagraphValidDate = $('<p> Tax Expire Date: ' + buyerList[i].CarValidityDate + '</p>');
        listAnc.append(carImag);
        listAnc.append(listHeader);
        listAnc.append(listParagraph);
        listAnc.append(listParagraphValidDate);
        listItem.append(listAnc);
        $("#buyer-listview").append(listItem);
    }

    $("#buyer-listview").listview("refresh");
}
```

It doesn't show any message.

Comment: to call `$.mobile.loading("show/hide")` on `pageinit`, you need to wrap the code in `setTimeout(function () { //code }, 0);` for other events `pageshow` and `pagehide` it works directly without delay.

Comment: I wrap it with the setTimeout. But not showing. @Omar

Comment: which jq & jqm versions are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js

Comment: use `.on("pageinit", "#page_id", ...` not `.delegate` and `$.mobile.loading("show")` / `$.mobile.loading("hide")`.

Comment: maybe because loading data is fast, if you test it by delay calling `createCarTaxValidPage();` you will see that its working as in the demo below.

Answer (score 0):

1. `.delegate` is deprecated and replaced with `.on`.

   ```
   $(document).on("pageinit", "#cartaxvalidityPage", function () { });
   ```
2. On `pageinit` event, use `setTimeout` to dela showing loading message.

   ```
   setTimeout(function () {
     $.mobile.loading("show");
   }, 10);
   ```
3. Use `$.mobile.loading("show")` and `$.mobile.loading("hide")`

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cNsES/)**